# How to redirect www to root (@)?

Tags: vercel

How do I setup an alias so that www.mydomain.com permanently redirects to mydomain.com using Zeit now CLI?

I tried `now dns add mydomain.com www CNAME mydomain.com` but it does not work.

It seems `* CNAME alias.zeit.co` is prioritized over `www CNAME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add an alias pointing your deployment to your root domain.

```
now alias my-deployment-url.now.sh example.com
```

Then you need to add a redirect. Since this is not possible with DNS, you need to have some web server emit a 301/302 redirect. In this case, we'll make a new deployment.

```
now -e REDIRECT_URL=https://example.com now-examples/redirect
```

Now that we have this new "redirect" deployment, we'll alias it as www like so:

```
now alias https://redirect-otytioldup.now.sh www.example.com
```

See [the docs](https://zeit.co/docs/guides/redirect) for more info.